# Chrome Browser console gets closed within a few seconds after I open it. How do I fix this issue>

Tags: google-chrome, browser, console, workspace, developer-tools

My Google Chrome Browser console gets closed within a few seconds after I open it. This issue is only happening after I had added my eclipse workspace folder under source.

Tried a few steps to fix this, but none worked -

- I tried restarting the Browser again but the issue persists.
- Tried to remove the workspace folder but it is not listed under the "source"
  [image]